# Find index of cell in dateframe

Tags: python

I would like to modify the cell value based on its size.

If the dateframe is as below:

```
  A         B    C
 25802523   X1   2
 M25JK0010  Y1   1
 K25JK0010  Y2   1
```

I would like to modify the column 'A' and insert to another column. 
For example, if the first cell value the size of column A is 8. I would like to break it and get least 5 values, similarly others depend on their sizes of each cell.

Is there any way I'm able to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach to do this:

Sample df:

```
t = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['25802523', 'M25JK00010', 'KRJOJR4445']})
```

Get the count of each elements of A:

```
t['Count'] =(t['A'].apply(len))
```

Then write a condition to replace:

```
t.loc[t.Count == 8, 'Number'] = t['A'].str[-5:]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
t = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['25802523', 'M25JK00010', 'KRJOJR4445'],
                  'size': [2, 1, 8]} )
```

Define a dictionary of your desired final length based on the corresponding size. Here if the size is 8 I will take the 5 last characters

```
size_dict = {8: 5, 2: 3, 1: 4}
```

Then use a simple `pandas apply`

```
t['A_bis'] = t.apply(lambda x: x['A'][len(x['A']) - size_dict[x['size']]:], axis=1)
```

The result is

```
0      523 >> 3 last characters (key 2)
1     0010 >> 4 last characters (key 1)
2    R4445 >> 5 last characters (key 8)
```